# error: Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

I've coppied source coudes from other's.  I got problem with kotlin version. I changed the version in build.gradle file, but it still happens. How can I work arrange this

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10' // Change here
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

}

```
─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
```

│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                       │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then │
│ update /Users/rocat/Downloads/Awesome-Flutter-Layouts-master/android/build.gradle:           │
│ ext.kotlin_version = ''                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

In `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

Bump the following line to something matching:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

**Edit:**

Also change to this in `android/gradle/build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

Comment: It still same,, is there any other way? @Robert Sandberg

Comment: I've added a line, make sure you bump that as well.